# getCount() in android not returning number of rows

Tags: android, android-cursor

Please check my code.. getCount() method is not returning the number of rows in the table.. also it gives runtime exceptions and on opening the app it gives alert message "Unfortunately app stopped working"

```
 public int getTotalRows() {

    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_OOPBASICS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    cursor.close();


    return cursor.getCount();


}
```

The method should return number of rows in the table.

Comment: because you have closed the cursor and hence no further actions can be applied to it, store the values in a variable then close the cursor and then return the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're closing the Cursor..that's why.

do the **cursor.close();** after the **cursor.getCount()**

```
 public int getTotalRows() {

   String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_OOPBASICS;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

   if (cursor != null) {
      count = cursor.getCount();
      cursor.close();
   }

   return count;
}
```

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow.. I tried marking as correct but it was showing some message hence could not.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You look like you are requesting the actual rows, now the number of rows. Unless your method name is wrong you are looking for something like

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM tblName
```